# How to customise appearance of gradle change message bar in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, gradle-plugin

I am using solarized color theme in android studio with some customization,

**where i can modify the font and background color for the bar which showing gradle related messages like "sync now" ?**

[image]

Comment: I think,

You can not change "Sync Now" message color or font individually. When you change theme it will be changed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Preferences - Editor - Colors & Fonts - General - Editor - Notification background.

Here is the path I found in Android Studio.